# What's a better solution for my shopping cart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, shopping-cart

I'm currently programming the shopping cart of my webshop and i was wondering what the best solution is to do this.

I currently have 5 sessions that includes data of the items that have been added by the user to save sql stress. But i just read that using sessions isn't good for performance and that the server destroys sessions when the maximum has been reached (I've no idea what the maximum is and i don't expect that hundreds of users buy items at the same time, only a few).

Conclusion, what's better to use 5 sessions to save data of the products or to use queries to get all the information of the products everytime the user visits the shopping cart?

Any other suggestion is welcome as well!

Comment: _"just read that using sessions isn't good for performance and that the server destroys sessions when the maximum has been reached"_ - please provide a source for this. Anyway this question can't be reasonably answered, unless the answer you're looking for is "It depends".

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find the article anymore about the session performance. My internship college told me about the session destroying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to save carts to db

So the user will have a perpetual chart as on amazon.

And you can do data-mining on every shopping cart.

if the user is logged you can save the cart with the user id/key

if the user is anonimous you could use a cookie to identify the anonymous user

If you don't like perpetual cart you can put a timestamp on the saved cart

Sessions ends after the configurated timeout or when user closes its browser or when the application pool recycles.

I will use db query caching to save product info instead of session

anyway session or cache "stress" server memory, db query stress sql

someone will be stressed anyway.
IMHO the best way is to cache sql response so you can balance stress between memory and queries

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have decided to store the shopping cart into the database and delete it after a few days. So session time outs will be avoided. I didn't came up with the cookie part, thanks for that. Will use it for anonymous users. I can't vote up unfortunately, sorry.

Comment: @Jamie you don't need to delete the cart. they contains useful info. Just discard them when you query the database. No problem for the upvote. if you think i replied to your question mark it as solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are only expecting a few users buying from your webshop at any one time, then saving to the database should be no problem.

If you are worried about excess database stress, you could save the user's temporary cart to cookies. This saves the server having to worry about sessions - which will allow for webfarms if ever you need them - and allows you to harness the customer's machine to process basic things by means of JavaScript.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but on the other hand you would have to check the cookie if the details in it aren't modified. It would still be a better solution to use a few session though. Thanks for your reply!